# How can I select something before and after a certain element

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to select the first element with some condition (For example, `.some_class`)
which is after a certain element. I don't know the relation between the elements, they could be siblings, cousins, whatever, all I know is they're all in this #container.

HTML code:

```
<div id="container">
    <div class="subcontainer">
        <div id="before" class="some_class">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="this" class="some_class">
    <div>
    <div class="subcontainer">
        <div class="subcontainer">
            <div id="after" class="some_class">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
...
</div>
```

Given an element with the class "some_class" (in this case `#this`) i want to find the "some_class" elements that are immediately before (the `#before` div) or after (the `#after` div) said element.

Comment: try with $('.some_class').after() OR $('.some_class').before()

Comment: You cannot select an element before with pure css, but you can select the element after with .class + .element {}

Comment: Sure thing i'll edit the question to make it more clear

Comment: I think I understand. I don't think this should have been downvoted.

Comment: var element = $("#container").find(".some_class");

Comment: like http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/RST4C/1/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this :

```
var all = $('#container .some_class');
var before = all.slice(0, all.index(yourElement));
var after = all.slice(all.index(yourElement)+1);
```

[Demonstration](http://jsbin.com/AzEYATE/2/edit) (open the console)

Comment: Yep, this works. So involved in finding a pure jquery solution that I didn't think of using array functions. Thanks

Comment: you know what I mean... What would you call them, anyway? Also I just used all[index-1] and all[index+1] since I wanted the very next and previous element specifically.

Comment: @Bogdan I didn't know if you were aware that `index` and `slice` were jQuery (array like) functions.

Answer (score 0):

For all the nodes around that "some_class" element try,

```
$( "#this" ).siblings().css( "background-color", "red" );
```

For the next element,

```
$( "#this" ).next().css( "background-color", "red" );
```

And for previous element

```
$( "#this" ).prev().css( "background", "yellow" );
```

Comment: *"I don't know the relation between the elements, they could be siblings, cousins, whatever, all I know is they're all in this #container."*